# Script to load random page on page load/refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cycle

I'm looking for something that will allow me to have a page in the root directory randomly selected to load each time the page is first loaded and with subsequent reloads/refreshes.. I have an index.html and index2.html for example slightly different from each other in the root directory.

I have tried teh Googles but can't find anything / everything I have tried isn't working.

The javascript I'm currently trying try to use is:

```
var howMany = 3;  // number of pages below, count them.

howMany = howMany-1
var page = new Array(howMany+1);

page[0]="index.html";
page[1]="index2.html";
page[2]="index.html";

function rndnumber(){
    var randscript = -1;
    while (randscript < 0 || randscript > howMany || isNaN(randscript)){
        randscript = parseInt(Math.random()*(howMany+1));
    }
    return randscript;
}
quo = rndnumber();
quox = page[quo];
location.href=(quox);
```

If I test it locally it seems like it works but it gets stuck in an infinite and automatically reloading/refreshing loop for some reason. When I upload it to server there's no reloading loop but the randomization doesn't work, it just loads the index.html

I have a set up a test page here: http://www.samnorris.co.nz/test2/ which has both the index.html and index2.html in the root directory

Can anyone offer any clue why this might not be working properly and/or a better solution?

thanks!

Comment: (also, I realize the array should only specific 2 instead of 3 pages but it doesn't seem to make a difference anyway..)

Comment: if you keep redirecting the user every time they load/refresh the page they would get stuck in a redirection loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript is executed on the client on page load. So everytime you load the page, it randomly selects a page and redirects to that page. That page then has some JavaScript emebedded that when executed, selects a random page and loads that, ...

a better solution would be to handle the serving of the page on the server using a server side language. PHP for instance. The code would be something like this:

index.php

```
<?php
$randNumber = mt_rand(1,3);
if ( $randNumber == 1 )
{
    include 'index_1.html';
}
else
{
    include 'index_2.html';
}
```

Comment: could you give me a bit more of an idea how to set this up? (sorry, not super familiar with PHP)... if I upload index.php into the root path it doesn't seem to want to load? (access forebidden? is there something I have/haven't set in my htaccess file causing that?) Navigation to the index.php directly it just seems to be stuck loading (http://www.samnorris.co.nz/test2/index.php) or gives errors

Comment: It's giving you the error because the index.html, which you are trying to include, doesn't exist. Also the URL in this case stays the same. The server script just sends another (random) content to the user.

Comment: yeah sorry, I just fixed that.... now it seems to be embedding the entire second page into the first though o_O

Comment: okay, fixed my htaccess file to load index.php as root index - still got two problems though, it seems to conflict with my preloader script somehow causing it get stuck loading..... and as mentioned above it's embedding both entire pages in the one page

Comment: Maybe show us your entire code? index.php should only hold the code I wrote. Nothing else. And what is your 'preloader script' ?

Comment: whoops, I was trying to insert as inline code into index.html and renamed it as index.php - do I need to do a php include? preloader script is simply a script used to preload the content of the page... I'm trying to remember where the hell it's referenced in my code though...

Comment: the index.php file will include at random the correct html file. so yes, a php include (see my scrypt)

Comment: It actually will. Since php is server side. The server serves a random page on every request. And it does work. But have a better look at my script: index_1 has 33% chance of being shown, and index_2 66%: mt_rand returns 1,2 or 3 at random in my script

Comment: Ah-ha! Think I've got it! awesome, cheers buddy! :) thought it wasn't working at first but tried a few more refreshes, and voila!

Answer (score 1):

You have to, somehow, tell the script it has been already redirected. This could be probably achieved using location's hash:

```
if (location.hash === "#redirected") {
  location.hash = "";
}
else {
  quo = rndnumber();
  quox = page[quo];
  location.href=(quox) + "#redirected";
}
```

Comment: would I just put that below that other code? ah...check out what it's doing now, haha: http://www.samnorris.co.nz/test2/  got the infinite reload/redirection loop on the server this time...

Comment: Not just below. Put it instead of those last 3 lines.

Comment: Okay cool, that works, but now I've got a somewhat unsightly #redirected tag in my URL..... don't suppose there's any way to hide it so the URL won't reveal that (or which page has loaded?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `location.hash` also contains the # symbol. Look at the edited code in my answer. ;-)

Comment: still shows the # symbol and the name of the page loaded - so far this is a working solution but not absolutely ideal unless I can figure out a way to mask the URL or something...

Comment: You can't do it much better on the client-side. ;-) If you don't want the URL to be visible, use the server-side solution provided by @Pinoniq.

Comment: This solution doesn't really work. It for instance won't work on 'refresh'. It also won't work when someone bookmarks the url with the #-hash.

Comment: It will work on refresh. That's why I remove the hash when the page is loaded. So nobody will actually see the hash and so it's hard to save the bookmark with the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate html file with the following content in the same dir as your `"index*.html"` files:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pages = [
        "index.html",
        "index2.html",
        "index3.html"
    ];

    function randomPage() {
        return pages[Math.round(Math.random() * (pages.length - 1))];
    }

    location.href= randomPage();
</script>
```